# Protobuf "Unresolved reference" with generated classes in Android Studio using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, datastore, protobuf-java

it's my first time diving in with protobuf and jetpack's DataStore but I've encountered an issue which is quite confusing.

I've created my .proto file in src/main/java/proto, it's really simple:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "com.test.appname.proto";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message WalkInfo {
  float distance = 1;
  bool run = 2;
}
```

Then I've written in kotlin a serializer class for some data in my app.

```
object WalkInfoSerializer : Serializer<Walker.WalkInfo>{
        override val defaultValue: Walker.WalkInfo
            get() = WalkInfo.getDefaultInstance()

        override fun readFrom(input: InputStream): Walker.WalkInfo {
            try {
                return WalkInfo.parseFrom(input)
            } catch (exception: InvalidProtocolBufferException) {
                throw CorruptionException("Cannot read proto.", exception)
            }

        }

        override fun writeTo(t: Walker.WalkInfo, output: OutputStream) {
            t.writeTo(output)
        }

    }
```

I've also set up my build.gradle file like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.14"

}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    //DataStore
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0-alpha05"
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0'
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.10.0"
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, the classes seem to be generated correctly and they even pop up in android studio's autocomplete.
The problem is that I can't get the project to compile as I can't seem to find a way to resolve the "Unresolved Reference" for the methods generated (like getDefaultInstance(), parseFrom(), writeTo()
Even by writing the full class path it won't work.

[image: android studio autocomplete]

Am I missing something? I've tried to play around with build.gradle and the proto file with some settings I found in their documentation but I still couldn't get it to work

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Went to sleep, woke up, and knew the answer to my problems.
Dumb brain managed to do 1 + 1 during the night.

I realized that if the proto classes are being generated, I should not be defining them myself in kotlin code.

I had a WalkInfo message that generated a WalkInfo class, but I also had a WalkInfo class already with some methods in it. This is what was confusing the compiler.

After further research I realized that classes generated by proto are not even meant to be extended, they are supposed to be just data containers.

What I ended up doing is renaming my message to WalkInfoStorage while also keeping my WalkInfo kotlin class, I'll then be handling generating WalkInfo instances from the serialized data

Comment: Thanks, you saved my night! :) my brain dont need to think for solution 1+1 .